# Composer update my Bundles dependencies

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I created a new Symfony 3.1.2 project where I started developing some new Bundles I plan to reuse in the future. So my directory structure is like this:

```
app/
bin/
src/
   AppBundle/
   MyVendorName/
      CoolBundle/
         Controller/
         composer.json
         ...other files and folders...
      AwesomeBundle/
         Controller/
         composer.json
         ...other files and folders...
test/
var/
web/
composer.json
...other files...
```

Both `CoolBundle` and `AwesomeBundle` dependes on third-party libraries (defined on each `composer.json`).

Now, is there a way I can call `composer update` on the project and it will also update the dependencies of my bundles?

Answer (score 1):

Y found a solution using composer's repositories.

I moved my bundles to a new folder called bundles (arbitary named). This is necessary as Symfony autoloads by default any Bundle in the `src` folder, and I don't know what will happen if they are autoloaded twice (maybe someone can clarify this). So the new folder structure is

```
app/
bin/
src/
   AppBundle/
bundles/
   MyVendorName/
      CoolBundle/
         Controller/
         composer.json
         ...other files and folders...
      AwesomeBundle/
         Controller/
         composer.json
         ...other files and folders...
test/
var/
web/
composer.json
...other files...
```

Then on my app's `composer.json` file (the one at the bottom) I added

```
...,

"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "bundles/MyVendorName/*"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "myvendorname/coolbundle": "@dev",
    "myvendorname/awesomebundle": "@dev",
},
...
```

Now when I run `composer update` it adds this bundles (as long as they have a valid `composer.json` file) in the `vendor` folder of my project including their dependencies, and they are autoloaded.

The local bundles are added using **symlinks** so any changes I make in the bundles affect inmediatly the app. For more info take a look at [composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path).